# I need to create a first and last button for my ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Hello need help with a class trying to figure out how to create a first and last button in a fragment that will jump to the first item in a ViewPager and the last item in a ViewPager I'm a bit lost with how to implement. Here is the fragment.

```
public class CrimeFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_CRIME_ID = "crime_id";
private static final String DIALOG_DATE = "DialogDate";
private static final int REQUEST_DATE = 0;

private Crime mCrime;
private EditText mTitleField;
private Button mDateButton;
private CheckBox mSolvedCheckBox;
private Spinner mSpinner;
private Button mFirstButton;
private Button mLastButton;


public static CrimeFragment newInstance(UUID crimeId) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(ARG_CRIME_ID, crimeId);

    CrimeFragment fragment = new CrimeFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_DATE) {
        Date date =
                (Date) data.getSerializableExtra(DatePickerFragment.EXTRA_DATE);
        mCrime.setDate(date);
        updateDate();
    }
}

private void updateDate() {
    mDateButton.setText(mCrime.getDate().toString());
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    UUID crimeId = (UUID) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_CRIME_ID);
    mCrime = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrime(crimeId);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, container, false);

    mTitleField = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
    mTitleField.setText(mCrime.getTitle());
    mTitleField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(
            CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(
            CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    mDateButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
    updateDate();
    mDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            DatePickerFragment dialog = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(mCrime.getDate());
            dialog.setTargetFragment(CrimeFragment.this, REQUEST_DATE);
            dialog.show(manager, DIALOG_DATE);
        }
    });

    mSpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.crime_severity);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getActivity(),
            R.array.severity_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            mCrime.setSeverity((String) mSpinner.getSelectedItem());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

        }
    });

    mSolvedCheckBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.crime_solved);
    mSolvedCheckBox.setChecked(mCrime.isSolved());
    mSolvedCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
            new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                    mCrime.setSolved(isChecked);
                }
    });

    mFirstButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.first_crime_button);
    mFirstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    mLastButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.last_crime_button);
    mLastButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });




    return v;
}

}
```

Here is the Activity with the ViewPager.

```
public class CrimePagerActivity extends FragmentActivity{

private static final String EXTRA_CRIME_ID =   "com.martin.android.criminalintent.crime_id";

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private List<Crime> mCrimes;


public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, UUID crimeId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, CrimePagerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID, crimeId);
    return intent;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_crime_pager);

    UUID crimeId = (UUID) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager)        findViewById(R.id.activity_crime_pager_view_pager);
    mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(this).getCrimes();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Crime crime = mCrimes.get(position);
            return CrimeFragment.newInstance(crime.getId());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mCrimes.size();
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < mCrimes.size(); i++) {
        if (mCrimes.get(i).getId().equals(crimeId)) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

For the First button Im pretty sure I just need to set item to 0? For last button I need to set item to size - 1 just not sure how to do that.

Comment: use viewpager's onpageChangeListener

Comment: Just use to setCurrentItem(position of page) method for set on specific page.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your `CrimePagerActivity`, write two method's to jump to the ViewPager `first` page and `last` page.

**CrimePagerActivity.java:**

```
    public void jumpToFirstPage() {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }

    public void jumpToLastPage() {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mCrimes.size() - 1);
    }
```

2. Call those method's from `mFirstButton` and `mLastButton` click listener method:

**CrimeFragment.java:**

```
    mFirstButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.first_crime_button);
        mFirstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((CrimePagerActivity)getActivity()).jumpToFirstPage();   
        }
    });

    mLastButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.last_crime_button);
        mLastButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((CrimePagerActivity)getActivity()).jumpToLastPage(); 
        }
    });
```

Hope this will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was a answer that I was given by the teacher incase anyone is interested.

```
 mFirstButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.first_crime_button);
    mFirstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.activity_crime_pager_view_pager);
            pager.setCurrentItem(0);

        }
    });

    mLastButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.last_crime_button);
    mLastButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.activity_crime_pager_view_pager);
            pager.setCurrentItem(CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrimes().size()-1);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Create two button and on click set

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(0); // for top
```

and

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(mCrimes.size()); // for last
```